# PancakeSwap V2 swapExactTokensForTokens not working, getting stuck

Tags: contract-invocation, nodejs, ethers.js, pancakeswap, swaps

I am unable to get this working with `ethers.js`. I know there are many similar questions for this specific topic, but none of the answers seem to work for me. My attempt is mostly based on [Noob Troubleshooting failed BSC transaction using ethers.js and Pancakeswap v2 router](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/99320/noob-troubleshooting-failed-bsc-transaction-using-ethers-js-and-pancakeswap-v2-r).

My code is the following:

```
const ethers = require('ethers');

const addresses = {
    WBNB: '0xbb4CdB9CBd36B01bD1cBaEBF2De08d9173bc095c',
    BUSD: '0xe9e7cea3dedca5984780bafc599bd69add087d56',
    factory: '0xcA143Ce32Fe78f1f7019d7d551a6402fC5350c73',
    router: '0x10ed43c718714eb63d5aa57b78b54704e256024e',
    recipient: '0xE00e552a0e18ca773a26f65cE957915D302CBE10'
}

const PRIVATE_KEY = ""

const mygasPrice = ethers.utils.parseUnits('5', 'gwei');

const WSS = "wss://*.bsc.quiknode.pro/*/"
const provider = new ethers.providers.WebSocketProvider(WSS);

const wallet = new ethers.Wallet(PRIVATE_KEY);
const account = wallet.connect(provider);

const router = new ethers.Contract(
    addresses.router,
    [
        'function swapExactTokensForTokens(uint amountIn, uint amountOutMin, address[] calldata path, address to, uint deadline) external returns (uint[] memory amounts)'
    ],
    account
);


const init = async () => {
    console.log("Test TX");

    let tokenIn = addresses.WBNB, tokenOut = addresses.BUSD;

    const amountIn = ethers.utils.parseUnits('0.0005', 'ether');
    const amountOutMin = 0;

    console.log("Starting swap...");

    const tx = await router.swapExactTokensForTokens(
        amountIn,
        amountOutMin,
        [tokenIn, tokenOut],
        addresses.recipient,
        Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 60 * 20, // 20 minutes from the current Unix time
        {
            gasPrice: mygasPrice,
            gasLimit: 500000
        }
    );
    console.log("Swap done!");
    const receipt = await tx.wait();
    console.log("Transaction receipt");
    console.log(receipt);
}

init();
```

When I run this code, it gets stuck.

```
Test TX
Starting swap...
```

The wallet generated from the private key is the same as the recipient address (`0xE00e552a0e18ca773a26f65cE957915D302CBE10`), and there is enough `WBNB` balance. I just tried to do a manual swap on pancakeswap V2 (`WBNB` to `BUSD`) and it worked flawlessly (`https://bscscan.com/tx/0xe3351e82ed4a86e18e164ba47b44bb7fa74faaeda67f8b7e3486f6410e5b50b9`).

I am currently out of ideas, and I don't know how to debug this further.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `swapExactETHForTokens` for swapping WBNB to a token, NOT `swapExactTokensForTokens`. `swapExactTokensForTokens` is for swapping a non-BNB token to another non-BNB token. (At least, that is what I can think of.)

Comment: I don't think this is the answer. I know for a fact that you can call `swapExactTokensForTokens` to swap `WBNB` for other tokens. (I have done it in the past, using web3py). Also all other answers seem to agree with me on this.

As I understand it, `swapExactETHForTokens` would be used to swap `BNB`, not `WBNB`.

Comment: Yeah, seems I missed that. I thought you were trying to directly swap from BNB. I'm looking at the code again now to try and find a potential issue.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I am really lost on this one. It probably has something to do with the asynchronous stuff, which I am not at all familiar with.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it was a problem with the BSC node (QuickNode). I have just started using this service but so far it looks very unreliable. Perhaps I am doing something else wrong, I would love to know what.

After changing the `WSS` to `wss://bsc-ws-node.nariox.org:443` it works.